# How to calculate percentage over a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a scenario simulating to a dataframe which looks something like below.

```
Area   Type    NrPeople     
1      House    200
1      Flat     100
2      House    300
2      Flat     400
3      House   1000
4      Flat     250
```

How want to calculate and return the Nr of people per area in descending order, but most important I struggle to calculate the overall percentage.

Result should look like this:

```
Area   SumPeople      %     
3       1000        44%
2        700        31%
1        300        13%
4        250        11%
```

See code sample below:

```
HouseDf = spark.createDataFrame([("1", "House", "200"), 
                              ("1", "Flat", "100"), 
                              ("2", "House", "300"), 
                              ("2", "Flat", "400"),
                              ("3", "House", "1000"), 
                              ("4", "Flat", "250")],
                              ["Area", "Type", "NrPeople"])

import pyspark.sql.functions as fn 
Total = HouseDf.agg(fn.sum('NrPeople').alias('Total')) 

Top = HouseDf\
    .groupBy('Area')\
    .agg(fn.sum('NrPeople').alias('SumPeople'))\
    .orderBy('SumPeople', ascending=False)\
    .withColumn('%', fn.lit(HouseDf.agg(fn.sum('NrPeople'))/Total.Total))\
Top.show()
```

This fails with: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'DataFrame'

Any ideas welcome how to do this !

Answer (score 9):

You need window function-

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn 
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank,sum,col
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)

HouseDf\
.groupBy('Area')\
.agg(fn.sum('NrPeople').alias('SumPeople'))\
.orderBy('SumPeople', ascending=False)\
.withColumn('total',sum(col('SumPeople')).over(window))\
.withColumn('Percent',col('SumPeople')*100/col('total'))\
.drop(col('total')).show()
```

output :

```
+----+---------+------------------+
|Area|SumPeople|           Percent|
+----+---------+------------------+
|   3|   1000.0| 44.44444444444444|
|   2|    700.0| 31.11111111111111|
|   1|    300.0|13.333333333333334|
|   4|    250.0| 11.11111111111111|
+----+---------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error seems to be pretty straight forward, `Total` is a data.frame and you can't divide an integer by a dataframe. First, you could convert it to an integer using `collect`

```
Total = HouseDf.agg(fn.sum('NrPeople').alias('Total')).collect()[0][0]
```

Then, with some additional formatting, the following should work

```
HouseDf\
    .groupBy('Area')\
    .agg(fn.sum('NrPeople').alias('SumPeople'))\
    .orderBy('SumPeople', ascending = False)\
    .withColumn('%', fn.format_string("%2.0f%%\n", col('SumPeople')/Total * 100))\
    .show() 

+----+---------+----+
|Area|SumPeople|   %|
+----+---------+----+
|   3|   1000.0|44%
|
|   2|    700.0|31%
|
|   1|    300.0|13%
|
|   4|    250.0|11%
|
+----+---------+----+
```

Though I'm not sure if `%` is a very good column name as it will be harder to reuse, maybe consider naming it something like `Percent` or such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach to avoid the `collect` step:

```
HouseDf.registerTempTable("HouseDf")

df2 = HouseDf.groupby('Area').agg(f.sum(HouseDf.NrPeople).alias("SumPeople")).withColumn("%", f.expr('SumPeople/(select sum(NrPeople) from HouseDf)'))
df2.show()
```

I haven't tested, but my guess is that this will perform faster than the other answers in this post

This is equivalent (the physical plan is very similar) to something like this:

```
HouseDf.registerTempTable("HouseDf")
sql = """


select g, sum(NrPeople) as sum, sum(NrPeople)/(select sum(NrPeople)  from HouseDf) as new
from HouseDf 
group by Area

"""

spark.sql(sql).explain(True)
spark.sql(sql).show()
```

You almost certainly don't want to use the option with the `window` that spans the whole dataset (like `w = Window.partitionBy()`).  In fact Spark will warn you about this:

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```